# Internal server error using htaccess-redirect

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess in my WP-Blog and want to redirect e.g.

http://blog.clever4ever.at/?feed=rss2&cat=6

to

http://blog.clever4ever.at/?cat=6

My script:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^feed=rss2&cat=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule /?$ /?cat=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Unfortunately i get an internal server error, and don't know why... Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working due to a mistake in your regex where you have used this regex:

```
 /?$
```

which will **match each and every URL every time and will cause looping** (and will cause internal server error).

You probably meant this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^feed=rss2&(cat=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /?%1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^feed=rss2&cat=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?cat=%1 [L,R=301]
```

I replaced `/?$` with `^`